# Order of promise resolution using $q.all in AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, angular-promise

I'm unsure about the order of functions run in this scenario:

```
let results = [];
let p = [];
p.push(Service.get('something-async').then(result => {
    results.push(result)
});
p.push(Service.get('something-else-async').then(result => {
    results.push(result)
});


$q.all(p).then(() => {
    console.log(results.length);
}
```

Will the .then() functions run prior to $q.all being resolved or after? What will the length of `results` be here?

Answer (score 0):

The answer, in case anyone else wants to know, is that the `then` functions of the individual promises are called before $q.all(p).then function. So `results` has a length of 2.